# How to request network data in Subgraph

Tags: node.js, subgraph

I want to use Get to request some tripartite data, waht should I do?

In Subgraph, I can get tokenURI, then i want to get token info use this tokenURI.

If i can use **node-fetch** or **axios**, i think this is easy, but Subgraph doesn't support this, so what do I do?